# about the series $\frac{1}{\sinh ^2(s)}$

Tags: calculus

I been reading the paper Novel integral representations of the Riemann zeta-function and Dirichlet eta-function, close expressions for Laurent series expansions of powers of trigonometric functions and digamma function, and summation rules of Sergey K. Sekatskii and he gives
$$\frac1{\sinh^2 x}=\frac1{x^2}-\frac13+\frac2{\pi^2}\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^{2n}\zeta(2n+2)$$

I have recalculated the series and gives
$$\frac{1}{\sinh ^2(x)}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } x^k \left(-2 (k+1) \pi ^{-k-2} \zeta (k+2) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{3}$$

What do you think?

Comment: Use $\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}k) =0 $ for odd $k$ and  $\pm 1$ for even $k.$ Re-index the sum and compare the results.

Comment: both series are different that of the  paper does not agree with the series of tayor

Comment: tayor=Taylor? At which point? There is no Taylor series at $x=0.$ What terms are different if you apply my first comment?

Comment: @jack-daurizio: The RHS **is even**, because $\cos(k\pi/2)$ makes the odd powers zero, see my first comment.

Comment: @gammatester: fine. In such a case, by restricting the second series to the even values of $k$ (the only relevant values) we find that the two representations are the same.

Comment: Sorry I made a Mistake the two series are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides of
$$ \sinh(x) = x \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
we get
$$ \frac{1}{\sinh^2 x}=\frac{1}{x^2}-2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\pi^2 n^2-x^2}{(\pi^2 n^2+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}-2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2}\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m(2m+1)\left(\frac{x}{\pi n}\right)^{2m}\tag{2} $$
and
$$ \frac{1}{\sinh^2 x}=\frac{1}{x^2}-2\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m(2m+1)\zeta(2m+2)}{\pi^{2m+2}}\,x^{2m}\tag{3}$$
so Sergey K. Sekatskii is definitely right. On the other hand $\cos\frac{\pi k}{2}$ is zero for odd values of $k$, hence the two representations are equivalent.